# No data appears on BarChart for X entries when you use y-values as floats

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have tried to add a BarChart in my Code, nothing appear when I launch my app.

The purpose of my code is that: when the user enter the start date (StartDate),  end date (EndDate) and the product name, the graph should show the show price evolution during that period.

I have tried the code below, but nothing appear on the graph.

Please help to find the issue, or propose to me another code.

```
public class ResultProductStatisticsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private String mCategory;
private String mName;
private long mStartDate;
private long mEndDate;
private int mNumber = 0;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private ArrayList<ShopDetail> mDetail = new ArrayList<ShopDetail>();

private ArrayList<Float> mPriceList = new ArrayList<Float>();
protected Typeface mTfLight;
private  Typeface mTypeFaceLight;



private TextView mMontextViewtest;


private BarChart mChart;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.result_product_statistics_activity);




    mChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.m_barchart);
   // mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(this);

    mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
    mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);

    mChart.setDescription("");

    // if more than 60 entries are displayed in the chart, no values will be
    // drawn
    mChart.setMaxVisibleValueCount(60);

    // scaling can now only be done on x- and y-axis separately
    mChart.setPinchZoom(false);

    mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
    // mChart.setDrawYLabels(false);

    AxisValueFormatter xAxisFormatter = new DayAxisValueFormatter(mChart);

    XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
    xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
    xAxis.setTypeface(mTfLight);
    xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xAxis.setGranularity(1f); // only intervals of 1 day
    xAxis.setLabelCount(7);
    xAxis.setValueFormatter(xAxisFormatter);

    AxisValueFormatter custom = new MyAxisValueFormatter();

    YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setTypeface(mTfLight);
    leftAxis.setLabelCount(8, false);
    leftAxis.setValueFormatter(custom);
    leftAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);
    leftAxis.setSpaceTop(15f);
    leftAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

    YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
    rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
    rightAxis.setTypeface(mTfLight);
    rightAxis.setLabelCount(8, false);
    rightAxis.setValueFormatter(custom);
    rightAxis.setSpaceTop(15f);
    rightAxis.setAxisMinValue(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

    Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
    l.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.BELOW_CHART_LEFT);
    l.setForm(Legend.LegendForm.SQUARE);
    l.setFormSize(9f);
    l.setTextSize(11f);
    l.setXEntrySpace(4f);
    // l.setExtra(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS, new String[] { "abc",
    // "def", "ghj", "ikl", "mno" });
    // l.setCustom(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS, new String[] { "abc",
    // "def", "ghj", "ikl", "mno" });
    init();

    mChart.setMarkerView(new XYMarkerView(this, xAxisFormatter));
}




private void init(){
    mCategory = Myrecord.getSearchShopCategory(this);
    mName = Myrecord.getSearchShopName(this);
    mStartDate = Myrecord.getSearchStartTime(this);
    mEndDate = Myrecord.getSearchEndTime(this);


    if(mStartDate == -1){
        mStartDate = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    if(mEndDate == -1){
        mEndDate = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    }



    Thread thread = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            MyDB db = new MyDB(ResultProductStatisticsActivity.this);
            ArrayList<MyDetail> detailList = db.getMyDetailByAll(mCategory, mName, -1, 0, -1);

            for(int i = 0; i < detailList.size(); i ++){
                MyDetail detail = detailList.get(i);
                long date = detail.date;

                if(date >= mStartDate && date <= mEndDate){

                    mPriceList.add(db.getPriceGoodsByOwnName("ALEVONS")+0f);
                }
            }

            ResultProductStatisticsActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                     setData(mPriceList);
                }
            });
        }

    };
    thread.start();
}


private void setData(ArrayList<Float> mPriceList) {

    mChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinValue(mStartDate);
    mChart.getXAxis().setAxisMaxValue(mEndDate);

    ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

    for (int i = 0; i < mPriceList.size(); i++) {
        yVals1.add(new BarEntry(i , mPriceList.get(i)));
    }

    BarDataSet set1;

    if (mChart.getData() != null &&
            mChart.getData().getDataSetCount() > 0) {
        set1 = (BarDataSet) mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(0);
        set1.setValues(yVals1);
        mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } else {
        set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "Evolution du prix produit");
        set1.setColors(ColorTemplate.MATERIAL_COLORS);

        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
        dataSets.add(set1);

        BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
        data.setValueTextSize(10f);
        data.setValueTypeface(mTfLight);
        data.setBarWidth(0.9f);

        mChart.setData(data);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess, without any more details provided: your're setting the x-axis min and max values to the start and end date. I'm guessing this is encoded in unix time, so you have something like `1470614400` and `1471219200`.

Now looking at your data, it will start with `0` and go up to the number of prices you have in your price list (`mPriceList.size()`). So with 10 prices we'd have values at `0` through `9`. However, since your x-axis starts at `1470614400`, no data will be shown (although the axis, gridlines etc. should be visible).

So in order to fix your code (depending on how your price list is structured, this example assumes one price every hour), you'd need to change your code in `setData` to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mPriceList.size(); i++) {
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(mStartDate + i * 3600, mPriceList.get(i)));
}
```

If you have a list of dates associated with the price values, you can also simply do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < mPriceList.size(); i++) {
    yVals1.add(new BarEntry(mDateList.get(i), mPriceList.get(i)));
}
```

Comment: But mDateList.get(i) have value something like 1470614400 so the graph will never appear

Comment: Have you tried it? Remove all calls to `setAxisMinValue` and `setAxisMaxValue` for your x-axis, as the chart library automatically caculates the bounds for you. It should work then.

Answer (score 0):

We the reply of(@TR4Android),

I have update my code such below and I can get the graph:

```
        float start = 0f;

    mChart.getXAxis().setAxisMinValue(start);
    mChart.getXAxis().setAxisMaxValue(mPriceList.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < mPriceList.size(); i++) {
        yVals1.add(new BarEntry(i , mPriceList.get(i)));
    }
```

But I have a bit issue with start date end date where each item has been bought. I have put each date in array list but I don't see how I can put it on xAxis. The Array list is :

```
private ArrayList<Long> mDateList = new ArrayList<Long>();
```

One example of mDateList value is 2016/08/13

Comment: Does `mDateList` correspond to the `mPriceList` mentioned above? So is there one entry in `mDateList` for each entry in `mPriceList`?

Comment: Yes, mDateList contain the dates where  product in mPriceList has been bought.

Comment: Updated my answer. For this you'll need to change your x-axis min and max date to the original `mStartDate` and `mEndDate`.